# Jinja2 Accessing an specific index in List of Lists

Tags: html, python-2.7, jinja2

I'm new to Jinja and Python and having trouble getting my table to print out. I had something like this working and generating a table (though it would always miss index 0).

```
<table>
{% for row in table %}
  <tr>
    {% for cell in row %}
        <td>{{ cell }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

But I want to move to something like this so I can apply individual characteristics to different columns. One column will be links, one blue, etc. Though this code just gives me a bunch of blank `<td></td>` lines. Am I not accessing the index correctly?

```
<table>
{% for row in table %}
  <tr>
        <td>{{ row[0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row[1] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row[2] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row[3] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row[4] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row[5] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row[6] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row[7] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row[8] }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: What are the contents of your `row`? Is it a list? If it is another iterable like a queryset you cannot access using [..] indexing

Comment: @Selcuk Alright. So then is the best way with two for loops and then an if statement for each loop index?

Comment: Either that or you can use the dot notation to access elements of the row, but I cannot suggest anything because I don't know the contents of your row!

Comment: @Selcuk Sorry, yes the contents of each row is a list